# Searching from a text file and inserting all results into a listbox - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to create a function that allows the user to search for a keyword or phrase from a text file and have all lines from that text file that contain this keyword to be inserted into a listbox. I have the user input from an entry box labelled SearchE and want to insert all lines from the text file that contain the value stored under SearchE into the listbox. I have converted my text file into a list (mylist) as I have found this to help with other features when accessing a text file. I do not know how to insert all occurrences of the entry from the text file into the listbox.

```
for SearchE.get() in mylist:
    listbox.insert(END, SearchE.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a listbox you could fetch the entire file into the findAll() function from the re module and use regex to find all the matches of the search on the file

```
# Open file
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
# Feed the file text into findall(); it returns a list of all the found strings
strings = re.findall(r'some pattern', f.read())
```

This example is copied from [Google's introduction to Python](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)

Comment: I'm getting an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment` ?

Comment: @Anon23 you can run it without `r` if you know all escape-sequences you need in `'some pattern'`

Comment: The r before the pattern is just to indicate Python that you want it to use raw text, so it passes trough backslashes, it is optional. Plus, make sure there are no spaces between r and 'some pattern'